# C++ How do you solve namespaces in headers becoming undefined?

Tags: c++, header, namespaces

So I am currently making a small prototype for a bigger project I'm working on and I've gotten completely stuck on it. I am rather new to c++ and haven't worked with headers or namespaces before ever. The issue is that when i try to use my created namespace it fails completely and the compiler (clang) returns undefined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bark.hpp"

using namespace bark;

int main() {
    bark::woof();
}
```

Header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_HPP
#define FUNCTIONS_HPP

namespace bark {
    void woof();
}

#endif
```

file with functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bark.hpp"

void woof() {
    std::cout << std::endl << "woof" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: please include the complete error message. The problem is not that the namespace is undefined. Also there is a declaration of `bark::woof`. Problem is that there is no definition

Comment: ot: you do not need `prama once` *and* the conventional header guard at the same time.

Comment: Also, please add the names of the individual files so they can be referred to easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the implementation file, this definition:

```
void woof() 
{
 // ...
}
```

defines a function `woof` in the global namespace. So when you make the call:

```
bark::woof();
```

in the `main` function, there is no  `bark::woof` defined, and the linker will refuse to link the program.

---

To correctly define the `woof` from namespace `bark`, you need to either qualify it:

```
void bark::woof() 
{
 // ...
}
```

or else introduce the namespace `bark`, and define it inside:

```
namespace bark
{
  void woof() 
  {
    // ...
  } 
}
```